# What is the purpose of static and trusted nodes on BNB Smart Chain (BSC)?

Tags: evm, bsc, full-node

I would like to create my own BSC node, therefore I am learning about nodes. I understand the main part of the concept, but in the [BSC node docs](https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/fullnode.html#minimum-requirements) I found mentions to **static** and **trusted** nodes. The question is that in which use cases will I have to add these kind of nodes? I will use the node to send transactions and call smart contracts. Do I need to care with static and trusted nodes in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BSC forked from Ethereum, it uses the same `geth` with some customizations.

So according to [geth docs](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/peer-to-peer), static nodes can be used when there are firewall issues preventing from using UDP -

> Some firewall configurations can prevent UDP traffic from flowing. You can use the static nodes feature or admin.addPeer() on the console to configure connections by hand.

and trusted nodes are allowed to bypass the maxPeers limit -

> Geth supports trusted nodes that are always allowed to reconnect, even if the peer limit is reached. They can be added permanently via a config file /geth/trusted-nodes.json or temporary via RPC call. The format for the config file is identical to the one used for static nodes. Nodes can be added using the admin.addTrustedPeer() RPC-call over the js console and removed using the admin.removeTrustedPeer() call.